# Linksys WRT1900AC or Asus RT-AC68U as NAS and Print hubs

Tags: router, printer, nas, dd-wrt

I'm considering buying one of the mentioned wireless routers:

- Linksys WRT1900AC or WRT1900ACS
- Asus RT-AC68U

They both have two USB ports. I'd like to connect a USB hard drive (Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex 2TB) to one to actually get NAS and I was also thinking of connecting a USB EPSON printer (Stylus Photo RX640 which is printer **and scanner**) to the other port also getting a network attached printer that doesn't have networking built-in.

One of the more important things is that **I would also be flashing DD-WRT on either** as they both support it.

### Questions

1. **Without DD-WRT** I'm pretty sure connecting a USB disk should work as expected. But how about connecting a printer? Linksys says on its website that EPSON RX620 works which is predecessor to RX640 so the latter might work as well. But will it?
2. **With flashed DD-WRT** would anything change in regards to connecting hard drive and printer? Is there even a possibility to do such a thing?

Comment: Only Linksys can tell you whether the RX640 will work. Both the 620 and 640 are GDI printers, which are very tricky to network.

Comment: @hdhondt: Not only Linksys. Users that have both can also provide the info. :)